# Fetch a collection with a search term in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to have a collection in backbone that calls `/search/:searchTerm` to the server upon fetch.
I have the following line:

```js
this.collection.fetch({ data: {searchTerm: "user input"} });
```

Firebug tells me this leads to a GET http://localhost:4242/search?[object%20Object]
Can this only be done by writing myself the ajax call in the backbone router, or is there a smoother faster way?

Comment: Ok, so I've found a way to do that, but I'm not so happy with it; inside my collection extension, I call:

    url: function() { return '/search/' + $("#userInput").val(); }

Tell me there's a better way to do that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, but using jQuery.param seems to have fixed it, i.e.

```
this.collection.fetch({ data: jQuery.param({searchTerm: "user input"}) });
```

Comment: FYI this bug is now fixed in Backbone.js 0.5.2